# How to create and delete log file for failure project?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have tried to write the log file for the Jenkins job like SVN update, revert, build execution. As far as i searched, i found the entire log for each builds(whole job process) in Jenkins installed location.

Can we write separate log in separate text file only for the failed project and send as zip file through email? If we can, then please do let us know what plugin do i need to use to achieve this.

Also to delete the zip file created, what plugin do i need to use?

Regards,

Vadivel

Comment: Could anyone please help on this? It will be more useful to continue my project.